# OLE microsoft.office.interop.excel and better documentation

Tags: excel, vba, interop, ole, msdn

I am using the microsoft.office.interop.excel msdn site to be able to learn how to manipulate excel using OLE. However it is very difficult to be able to navigate through these documentations. For a trivial example, the Application.LanguageSettings should have members of its own, but from the site it's impossible to be able to locate them (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.languagesettings(v=office.14).ASPX).
Does anyone know of a better way to get this information? Is there another manual/reference? Or can one 'inspect' the object returned (for example Application.LanguageSettings returns an object, can we explore what its members are without actual documentation?). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

and then you're sent to the Object iteself

[image]

---

theres nothing *hard* about it

Comment: hmm someone please give me -1 for lack of attention

Comment: i used to find it difficult to navigate around msdn developer reference too but once you get grips on it it becomes quite easy

Answer (score 0):

There is an object browser that's built into VBA, under the View menu:

[image: VBA Object Browser]

Comment: ok thanks this is quite useful in excel